# Nginx and PHP8.2-FPM Session is not serving to other page

Tags: php, nginx

I have a VULTR VPS with Ubuntu 20.04 and Running Nginx as Web Server and PHP8.2-FPM as Backend Scripting Language. I installed Nginx + PHP8.2-FPM through Hestia Control Panel, I found a strange issue with PHP Session. The sessions are stored in a file like **`sess_ff7flo8l32adi9lkfp1ddl08vp`** at **`/tmp`** folder every time a page loaded with **`session_start();`**

Resulting that a saved session like **`$_SESSION['username']`** at **`page1.php`** is not accessible at **`page2.php`** on same browser

In my localhost with XAMPP it is working fine. Found that a single session file at **`C:/XAMPP/temp`** is being created at loading of **`page1.php`** and the stored sessions can be retrievable at **`page2.php`**. At loading of **`page2.php`** no new session file is created.

I am unable to figure-out the fix. Compared both **`php.ini`** files of XAMPP and PHP8.2-FPM and can't found any difference there.

**page1.php below**

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 $_SESSION['username'] = 'someuser';
 ?>
```

**page2.php below**

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 echo 'Session Value: ' . $_SESSION['username'];
 ?>
```

Getting error in page2.php as **`Warning: Undefined array key "username"`**

Anyone kindly help me to fix it out? Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have cookies disabled in your browser?

Comment: Cookies status is "Standard preloading" in Chrome browser

Comment: Check the server's php.ini file for session location and verify group/owner and directory permissions.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of researching and brainstromings the final fix done by updading the Ubuntu Operating System. Some missing dependencies required for PHP-FPM package to handle sessions by PHP PID.

Or it also change operationg system from Ubuntu to Debian or CenOS also works.